# What would be an example of a tautology in first-order logic involving a definite sequence of quantifiers?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question might be silly, but while teaching a tutorial as a TA, I suddenly had the need to bring up a tautological statement in first order logic that involved the quantifiers $\forall\exists\forall\exists$ in this order. That is, a tautology of the form $\forall x\exists y\forall z\exists w $ $\phi(x,y,z,w)$ for some first order formula $\phi$. This came up while I was trying to convey to the class the essence of skolemization in this case. However, for some reason, I just couldn't come up quickly with such an example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A usage that is at least somewhat common is that a "tautology" in first order logic is only a formula obtained by replacing the variables in a propositional tautology by first-order formulas. There are no first-order tautologies of that sort which have leading quantifiers. There are logically valid formulas which have leading quantifiers, such as $(\forall x)(\exists y)(\forall z)(\exists w)[x = x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always $(y=x)\land (w=z)$ of course. But this has the disadvantage that $w$ doesn't need to depend on $x$, though. The best I can think of where this is not the case would be something like

$$(y\ne x \lor z=x) \land (z=x \to w=y) \land (z\ne x \to w=x)$$
In a structure with three elements, $w$ will have to depend on both $x$ and $z$.

Comment: @adrija: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Could you elaborate more about which structure you think my proposal is false in, and which celement you choose for $x$? I will then give you an $y$ that I claim makes it true, and you can then try to counter with a $z$ such that I can't give you a $w$ ...

Comment: No, I think this works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a stronger version of the infinitude of primes!

> Given any natural $m$, there is a least prime bigger than $m$.

Which can be stated over first-order arithmetic (with $+,\cdot,<,0,1$) as:
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

> $φ \overset{def}= \forall m\ \exists p\ ( p > m \land prime(p) \land \forall q\ ( q > m \land prime(p) \imp q \ge p ) )$.

where:

> $prime(p) \overset{def}\equiv p > 1 \land \forall x,y\ ( x \cdot y = p \imp x = p \lor y = p )$.

It is a good exercise to put $φ$ into Skolem-normal form and then Skolemize it.

Comment: The question asked for a _tautology_, that is, a sentence that is true in _all_ structures. There are certainly structures over the language $\{+,\cdot,<,0,1\}$ where your proposal would evaluate to false.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: in the usage I'm familiar with, not even all logical validities are first-order tautologies. I don't know how common each variant of the terminology is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Oh I didn't notice that the asker meant "logical tautology" rather than simply "true sentence over first-order PA". Anyway I thought it's more interesting to use an actual theory rather than just the base logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Yes some authors use "tautology" only for propositional tautologies where each propositional variable is replaced by some wff, but that can't be what the asker wants.

Comment: @Carl: I'm most used to that too, but when the OP explicitly asks for a "tautology" that begins with a string of quantifiers, it has to be in the wider sense of a logically valid formula.